# Update GIF image on button click tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a working code where tkinter application displays a still image from a GIF
And plays the same GIF file on clicking a button. It is working fine for a single GIF image.

What I want is to have an additional button for Next image and when I click on it, it should display next image and play that GIF image. How can I achieve it?
Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
canvas_width = 300
canvas_height =300

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()
file="jatan.gif"
info = Image.open(file)

frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains

# creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
im = [PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]
my_image = PhotoImage(file='jatan.gif')
canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor = NW, image=my_image)
count = 0
anim = None
def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]
    gif_label.configure(image=im2)
    count += 1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    anim = root.after(50,lambda :animation(count))


gif_label = Label(root,image="")
gif_label.pack()

start = Button(root,text="start",command=lambda :animation(count))
start.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to modify your code to achieve the new behavior. You must change your single file variable for a list of files and an index that points to the current image that is being displayed, such as

```py
files = ['gif1.gif', 'gif2.gif']
current_file = 0
```

Then, in all the places where you were using the file variable, you must use now the `files[current_file]`, i.e.:

```py
info = Image.open(files[current_file])
...
im = [PhotoImage(file=files[current_file], format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]
my_image = PhotoImage(file=files[current_file])
canvas_img = canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor = NW, image=my_image)
```

What you need now is to create a new button similar to the start one, but using another function that we can refer to as `next_gif()`. The function will retrieve the global variables that refer to the gif preview and frames and update it with the next image in the list, first updating the counter:

```py
def next_gif():
    global current_file
    global im

    current_file = (current_file + 1) % len(files)

    info = Image.open(files[current_file])
    frames = info.n_frames
    im = [PhotoImage(file=files[current_file], format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

    my_image = PhotoImage(file=files[current_file])
    canvas.itemconfig(canvas_img, image=my_image)
```

With this, it will work. However, you are loading all the frames again every time you are viewing the next image. If your number of gifs is small, you could build a list (or any similar data structure) with the same size as the number of gif files and store there all the frames data, using it as a cache-like mechanism, loading everything from the beginning or doing lazy loading ONLY the first time that you are visualizing that image.

Comment: I understood the concept. Thankyou so much. However, when I am putting it in my code and clickingon next button, the image is not changing :(

Comment: Do you mean the preview or the animation itself?